# GCM push notification depending on various conditions

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I wanted  a solution for the following problem:

I want to send notification specific to user like thank you message for one user and job  posted say another user. I am looking for a way so that I can send separate messages depending on user id and registration id.

I tried the following method ie.

When a new user registers then, that users userid gets created on the database. I thought if  I also create a registration id at the same time then  I can save that in a separate table on the server. which will contain user id  and registration_id and device type

But I noticed that at the time of GCM registration it is the Asynchronous task so I obtain it but till the user gets registered the id is still null. So it fails to get into the database.

If anyone has ideas on this particular problem. Or also has solved similar issue. Then do let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Gcm registration takes time as it is calling webservice to the google for registration. Therefore, registration Id will be null until user gets registered, so you can do to put gcm regisration call in the splash screen or at that place where gcm registration will get time to get registered

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is GCM registration often reuires some time to register. So there is a simple way to get your id registered in your database. One is, if you are using splash screen in your app, then try to register for GCM there and in onRegistered method of your GCMIntentService save your registrationId in preferences like this

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String regId) {
    Log.v("registrationId", regId);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("filename", 0);
    prefs.edit().putString("regid", regId).commit();
}
```

Now at the time of login you should try to get your registrationId from the prefs where you have stored in onRegistered method. But still there is 1-2 % chance that you will not get you regId here. so for that, you can make a separate api for GCM Registration, that you will hit((if your regid is not registered at Login time)) in Activity next to your LoginActivity to get the id registered to your database.

Secondally, if you are not using splash screen, then you have to make separate api for GCM Registration because there is more chance that you will not get your registrationId during login.